# Safari wont display background image in <div>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to get the background image to show in Safari. It works in IE and Chrome. I tried a couple of alternates with the `-webkit` prefix but no dice.

```
    <style type="text/css">

        h1, h2, h3, h4, p {position: relative; z-index: 10;}

        .jumbotron {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 3;
        }

        .jumbotron:after {
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url('img/carousel_island.png');
            bottom: 0;
            content: "";
            display: block;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }


    </style>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><strong>Welcome to Pepi's Island</strong></h1>
            <h3><strong>A place for kids to emotionally and socially learn and grow.</strong></h3>
            <br>
            <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems as though Safari only partially supports the usage of background image. http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari has some known bugs when using the short-hand `background` style; some features that are supported as individual CSS styles do not work when used together in a single `background` style.

I'm not sure whether the styles you're using here would be affected, but it's worth a try (I know for a fact that it bites `background-sizing` and others).

So I suggest splitting your `background` style out into separate styles:

```
background-color: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,.5));
background-image: url('img/carousel_island.png');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not the image no longer is painted as a gradient. This does get the image to show, and I could in theory alpha it out via a graphical tool.

Answer (score 0):

For my simple test it DOES show up, but your background is from white to 0.5 alpha-white. Try adding "background-color: red" to the CSS and you'll see your problem.

**EDIT:**

Some seconds after posting it I realized how stupid it was before actually testing it on safari, my bad.

I can confirm that it does not work in safari 5.xx on win7. But this worked for me, could you test if it does for you also?

```
.jumbotron:after {
  background-image:url('img/carousel_island.png');
}
```

If not, there are some more ideas that come to my mind (just long-shot-guesses):

```
1. mobile safaris have a limitation of 3MP or 5MP for PNG images
2. case of letters
3. try `./img/carousel_island.png`
4. A protocol restriction? Do you run it on a server or by `file://` or a `http(s)://` protocol?
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not the image no longer is painted as a gradient. This does get the image to show, and I could in theory alpha it out via a graphical tool.

Comment: thx. BTW You could also keep the original image and overlay it with an image that is while at the top and transparent down below, just saying

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.jumbotron:after {
content: url(img/carousel_island.png);
background-color:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,.5));
        bottom: 0;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: No dice. Still just grey box in Safari. Thanks.